# Http form not getting posted

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails

I'm having an issue with my grails application. I have a form whose method is set to POST, locally and on our staging server when the form is submitted everything works fine but on our production server when the form is submitted it just gets redirected as a GET request and obviously the action fails as no parameter are received by the controller.

Here the code from my .gsp page

```
<g:form name="unsubscribe" url="[action:'unsubscribeConfirm', controller:'subscriptions']" >
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <g:each in="${subCities}" var="subCity" status="i" >
                <div class="unsubscribe-select-cities-check" >
                  <g:checkBox name="subCity" value="${subCity.id}" checked="false" />${subCity.description}
                </div>
              </g:each><br/>
            <c:reasonSelect name="reason" class="unsubscribe-select-reason-drop-down" id="reason-select" />
            <textarea class="textarea-style" cols="55" rows="3" name="reasonTxt" id="reason-text" style="display: none;"></textarea>
            <input class="required input-style required" type="hidden" name="email" value="${person.email}">
            <g:submitButton name="Send" value="${g.message(code:'cl.email.unsubscribe.details.send')}"
                class="main-left-col-login-form-submit-register" style="float: left;"/>
  </g:form>
```

Even the view source both on staging and production is same.

Deployment structure is Apache infront of Tomat.

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys issue was by mistake a html base tag was added with url starting from https so the form was indeed getting posted with parameters to secure url and then redirected to unsecured url with no data.

Thats why controller received no parameters.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code looks fine.

I would check the Apache configuration. If it's happening as you say (POST gets redirected to a GET), then it's probably an Apache rewrite rule or similar.